# Convert 4.11 (integer.fraction) to float32

Tags: c, floating-point

Im getting a value from a register (SRCx_RATIO) from a SHARC DSP, the datasheet says:

[image: SRCRATx Register]
I'm using the following code to convert the value:

```
 // Convert the sample rate ratio to a float from 4.11 format.
   int_part = (((src_reg  >> 14) & BIT_0) * TWO_POW_3) +
              (((src_reg  >> 13) & BIT_0) * TWO_POW_2) +
              (((src_reg  >> 12) & BIT_0) * TWO_POW_1) +
              (((src_reg  >> 11) & BIT_0) * TWO_POW_0);

   frac_part = (((src_reg  >> 10) & BIT_0) * TWO_POW_MINUS1) +
               (((src_reg  >>  9) & BIT_0) * TWO_POW_MINUS2) +
               (((src_reg  >>  8) & BIT_0) * TWO_POW_MINUS3) +
               (((src_reg  >>  7) & BIT_0) * TWO_POW_MINUS4) +
               (((src_reg  >>  6) & BIT_0) * TWO_POW_MINUS5) +
               (((src_reg  >>  5) & BIT_0) * TWO_POW_MINUS6) +
               (((src_reg  >>  4) & BIT_0) * TWO_POW_MINUS7) +
               (((src_reg  >>  3) & BIT_0) * TWO_POW_MINUS8) +
               (((src_reg  >>  2) & BIT_0) * TWO_POW_MINUS9) +
               (((src_reg  >>  1) & BIT_0) * TWO_POW_MINUS10) +
                ((src_reg         & BIT_0) * TWO_POW_MINUS11);

   // Return the value to be used.
   *ratio = (int_part + frac_part);
```

The defines are:

```
// Power of 2 converstion used with 4.11 to float conversion.
#define TWO_POW_0       1.0F         // (2^0)
#define TWO_POW_1       2.0F         // (2^1)
#define TWO_POW_2       4.0F         // (2^2)
#define TWO_POW_3       8.0F         // (2^3)
#define TWO_POW_MINUS1  0.5F         // (2^-1)
#define TWO_POW_MINUS2  0.25F        // (2^-2)
#define TWO_POW_MINUS3  0.125F       // (2^-3)
#define TWO_POW_MINUS4  0.0625F      // (2^-4)
#define TWO_POW_MINUS5  0.03125      // (2^-5)
#define TWO_POW_MINUS6  0.015625F    // (2^-6)
#define TWO_POW_MINUS7  0.0078125F   // (2^-7)
#define TWO_POW_MINUS8  0.00390625F  // (2^-8)
#define TWO_POW_MINUS9  0.001953125F // (2^-9)
#define TWO_POW_MINUS10 0.000976563F // (2^-10)
#define TWO_POW_MINUS11 0.000488281F // (2^-11)

#define BIT_0  (1 << 0)
```

Anyone knows a better way to get this value?

Comment: What is `src_reg`? It is impossible to answer without knowing this.

Comment: src_reg is the value from register SRCx_RATIO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answers already showed how to do it by hand. The C math library on the other hand has an obsure and rarely used function to do just what you need:

```
float convert (uint32_t register_value)
{
  // extract field from register:
  uint32_t ratio = register_value & 0x7fff;

  // interpret as float with the exponent -11 applied:
  return ldexpf (ratio, -11);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are overthinking this with all that decomposing of the value into individual bits. No need to split the fractional part from the integer part either.

Let's say that your Q4.11 value represents the number
1010.01111001011<sub>2</sub> (10.47412109375 in decimal)
and is stored as
101001111001011<sub>2</sub>
in memory.

- The first step is to directly cast the raw integer to 32-bit floating point, disregarding the decimal point completely:

  101001111001011<sub>2</sub> → 010001101**01001111001011**000000000<sub>2</sub>

  which means 1.01001111001011<sub>2</sub> * 2<sup>14</sup>, the floating point representation of the value of the original integer.
- Next divide the floating point value by two to the power of the number of fractional bits in the fixed point value (2<sup>11</sup> in your case)

  (1.01001111001011<sub>2</sub> * 2<sup>14</sup>) / 2<sup>11</sup> = 1.01001111001011<sub>2</sub> * 2<sup>3</sup>

  which is just the floating point representation of 1010.01111001011. Done.

---

To do this in C / C++, you only need one line of code:

```
float val = (float)src_reg / pow(2, 11);
```

Or even better

```
float val = (float)src_reg / (1UL << 11);
```

which avoids linking to the math functions unnecessarily by replacing exponentiation with left shifts of 1.

Comment: this is magic if it works, Im using IAR compiler on a 32bit machine, I still need to wrap my head around it before I can go a put magic stuff on the code. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You got everything already in proper order and proper values. Right now it's like you're pointing at a bike and saying "*This! Is my new invention! I shall call it... 'Bike!'*". Well.. You don't need to invent things that already exists, so just do this:

```
int_part = src_reg>>11;
frac_part = (src_reg&0x3FF)*pow(2,-11);
*ratio = (int_part + frac_part);
```

>>11  is all you need to do to move it into the right place without anything around it.

\$3FF_{16}=1111111111_2\$, in words: it's \$10_{10}\$ ones in a row.

pow(2,-11) is \$2^{-11}\$, because I used two constants in its input, the compiler will make it into something like your other numerical constants.

I could also use /pow(2,11), but then it would use division, I don't know where your code will be used, but multiplication is always faster to perform than division. So that's why I chose *pow(2,-11).

I might have messed up one number somewhere, maybe it should be pow(2,-10) or pow(2,-12), and maybe it should be src_reg>>10 or src_reg>>12. I always mess those things up, so if you don't get the right answer, fiddle with it a little bit and you'll get the same answer as you're getting now.